# Laptop loses charge while plugged in

Tags: battery

Whenever I start my laptop, if I don't close it at the Windows 8 boot logo, it would shut off. The charger light would show green but turn orange quickly then shut off. Sometimes when I get it to boot, I can't do much because it would shut down fast. I keep it in the charger whenever it is booted but it loses charge instead of gaining charge. I tried to take the battery out (while it was on) but it instantly shut down. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? I wonder if you can confirm somehow that the charger is actually providing power. I had one fail like this and (part of) the reason was in the AC/DC transformer, not the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was the outlet itself.

Comment: Are you saying it was the outlet that the charger was plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to replace your battery. If a laptop is left plugged in too much and doesn't have a smart charger it will get overcharged which in turn will lead to reduced battery lifespan. As a troubleshooting step, try taking your battery out and turning on your computer with just the charger plugged in. This should work fine as long as the battery was the problem.

Comment: I tried taking the battery out, the laptop shuts down instantly.

Comment: But have you tried turning on the laptop with only the charger plugged in?

Comment: Actually it sounds to me like OP has a 3rd party charger without enough watts.

Comment: yes the charger was on @Tyson I don't know if it's the charger (it has been fixed a lot)